# \int_step_inline:nn in \textbf makes illegal parameter number

Tags: expl3

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn { 1 } {#1} % works fine
\textbf { \int_step_inline:nn { 1 } {#1} } % don't work
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

will make an error: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a."

It seems you cannot define a macro with parameter in `\textbf` (and other text font command).

There do have some methods to avoid this, (like `\cs_set:Nn \__my_aux: { \int_step_inline... }` or just use `\int_step_function:nN`), but is there any method to make `\textbf { \int_step_inline:nn { 1 } {#1} }` work?

(My environment: TeXLive 2021, expl3: Released 2021-08-27)

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/665  fixed in the latex sources for the next release, thanks for the report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally if `#` is inlined in a definition you can quote it as `##` however the latex2e text commands make an internal definition to check if the text is empty (which requires double `#`) but then uses the original argument to typeset (which requires single `#`) so there is no valid argument.

One possible approach would be to avoid the internal definition using e-tex tests for empty argument,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}% only needed with old latex versions

\makeatletter
\def \text@command #1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \let \check@icl \@empty
    \let \check@icr \@empty
  \else
    \iffalse %\ifx \reserved@a \space % need to think about this one
      \let \check@icl \@empty
      \let \check@icr \@empty
    \else
      \check@nocorr@ #1\nocorr\@nil
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn { 1 } {#1} % works fine

\textbf { \int_step_inline:nn { 1 } {#1} } % don't work
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Or better and more in the spirit of the original use a definition form that does not require ## so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}% only needed with old latex versions

\makeatletter
\def \text@command #1{%
  \edef \reserved@a {\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \ifx \reserved@a \@empty
    \let \check@icl \@empty
    \let \check@icr \@empty
  \else
    \ifx \reserved@a \space
      \let \check@icl \@empty
      \let \check@icr \@empty
    \else
      \check@nocorr@ #1\nocorr\@nil
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn { 1 } {#1} % works fine

\textbf { \int_step_inline:nn { 1 } {#1} } % don't work
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```